# CSS - Inverted border radius to draw a rounded corner

Tags: css

I would like to know if there is a way to do these borders only using CSS in a way that they follow this shape:

[image: Goal]

I am trying to use CSS pseudo-elements ::after and ::before but I can't feel a kind of gap between divs. Any suggestion?

[image: What I have so far]

Comment: If you add a code sample with what you tried, you might get some proper answers

Comment: Add `padding` and offset it with negative `margin` while hiding the `overflow` on the parent element.

Comment: no code - no chocolate. We can help, not do it for you. What have you done so far & where do you fail ? screenshots are useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pseudoelements to created rounded fragments and "clipped" borders.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.flex > * {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex > *:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -90px;
  width: 90px;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.flex > *:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -2px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 10px;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.flex > .one {
  width: 100px;
}

.flex > .two {
  width: 200px;
}

.flex > .three {
  width: 300px;
}

.flex > .four {
  width: 400px;
}

.degrees {
  /* circle styles */
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  /* styles for centering */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
   <div class="one">
     <div class="degrees">1°</div>
   </div>
   <div class="two">
     <div class="degrees">2°</div>
   </div>
   <div class="three">
     <div class="degrees">3°</div>
   </div>
   <div class="four">
     <div class="degrees">4°</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are styles. Therefore in tag style="-moz-border-radius:5px;"

```
input[type=email] {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 1.4px black;
    padding: 5px;
    padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: The `-moz-` vendor prefix for `border-radius` is [no longer necessary](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)